# Where to store the result of the computation on each element visited in the Visitor pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to use a visitor (in the sense of "separating algorithm from data structure"). All of the examples I see do something like a sum - where the visitor is SumVisitor and stores an ivar "Sum" that simply adds the value of each element that it visits. However, what if you want to associate the result of the computation with each element? As an easy case, say you want the algorithm (the visitor) to square each element that it visits. Where do you store the results? The only thing I can think of is something like a vector > that is stored in the visitor, but that seems strange. Any suggestions on how to do something like this?

Comment: What is the aim here?  To build an equivalent data structure with all the values squared?  To modify the original data structure?  Something else?

Comment: I just want to somehow have the elements associated with the result of the operation applied to them.

Comment: Consider implementing iterators; they're a much cleaner way of separating algorithms and data structures.

Comment: The visitor patterns is rather clumsy and inelegant, and it's generally considered a sort of "least evil" if you are stuck with a complex hierarchy. Be absolutely sure that you actually need it, and that your setup meets the requirements for a Visitor (e.g. stable class hierarchies). From what you've said it's hard to tell; for all we know there might be an extremely simple solution.

Comment: @larsmans - but the iterator should not contain the algorithm right? I thought the idea of Visitor was for the client to use an iterator to apply an algorithm to each item?

Kerrek SB - yea sorry I didn't want to go into too many specifics. I think Stuart Golodetz (below) has the right idea with an external map.

Comment: No, an iterator would only capture some order on the elements in a container. The algorithm would just loop through the container with the iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four options:

1) Store them in the original data structure somehow if there's somewhere to put them.

2) Store them in the visitor (e.g. use a map from elements to results).

3) Store them elsewhere, and pass 'elsewhere' to the visitor so it knows where to put the results.

4) Create a new data structure to store them as you go along.

Which you pick depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The exact cas I have is that I want to apply, say, 5 different operations like this and link the input to all of the outputs of those operations. I have created a struct Differences and an enum Differences::DifferenceTypes. So I want each Visitor to do a particular operation and store it in a particular DifferenceType in the differences struct, and I want all of these differences (together, the struct) to be associated with the item that created them. I think your #3 sounds close to what I want - can you comment on if you think this is reasonable thing to do?

Comment: It sounds like you want an external map from elements to Differences. Each visitor has a reference to this map, and fills in the appropriate data.